# UIStackView contentHuggingPriority doesn't work for filling available space

Tags: swift, autolayout, uistackview

I want to create a chat bottom bar with the following content, in a horizontal `UIStackView`:

- a `UITextField` on the left side, taking all the available space
- a label on the right with fixed size (default intrinsic content size)

Here is my code:

```
let messageTextField = UITextField()
messageTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
messageTextField.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
messageTextField.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)

let label = UILabel()
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label.text = "SEND"
label.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
label.textColor = .red

let sv = UIStackView()
sv.axis = .horizontal
sv.distribution = .fill
sv.alignment = .center
sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// constraint the stack view to the bottomBar view 
bottomBar.addSubview(sv)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    sv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomBar.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
    sv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomBar.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
    sv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomBar.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
    sv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomBar.topAnchor, constant: 8)
])

sv.addArrangedSubview(messageTextField)
sv.addArrangedSubview(label)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    messageTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo:sv.heightAnchor),
    // I didn't put any width constraint for textField because it make no sense, as I want it to take all the available space on the right 
])
```

With this code, the label is expanding its size and filling all the available space on the right, and the text field is not showing (inspector says width = 0); exactly the opposite of what I want.

I don't understand why it doesn't work because I explicitly configured it so it does not expand the label with:

```
label.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
```

and instead to expand the text field with:

```
messageTextField.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
```

What did I miss here? I have read through many SO answers, Apple documentation, and followed various tutorials and videos, but I'm not able to achieve this seemingly simple thing.

Comment: Did you tried to leave the default values of the stack view by commenting out sv.distribution = .fill and sv.alignment = .center? It should be by default both ‘fill’

Comment: Just tried but as you pointed out these are default values so it doesn't fix the problem :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it backwards...

Setting `Content Hugging Priority` means" *control how this element **hugs** its content*.

So, as an example, if you have a `UILabel` with only the letter "A" in it, a High content hugging priority will keep the label only as wide as that single letter.

So with these two lines:

```
label.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)

messageTextField.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
```

you've told auto-layout:

*keep `messageTextField` only as wide as its text, and allow `label` to stretch wider than its text*

What you want is:

```
// don't let label stretch at all
label.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)

// let message text field stretch if needed
messageTextField.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
```

The stack view will then stretch the text field to fill the available space.

Comment: That was that, thank you so much ! I'm not native english, I thought the word "hug" meant "huge" like "great", hence my confusion !

Answer (score 0):

I tried quickly on Xcode 12.3 on Simulator (iPhone 12 )

and leaving the default values to the stackview and the content hugging, worked for me:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Just added a view anchored to the bottom of the view controller for the purpose of the test
        let bottomBar = UIView()
        bottomBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(bottomBar)
        bottomBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0).isActive = true
        bottomBar.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
        let messageTextField = UITextField()
        messageTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        messageTextField.backgroundColor = .cyan

        // LEAVING DEFAULTS
        //messageTextField.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
        //messageTextField.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)

        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.text = "SEND"

        // LEAVING DEFAULTS
        //label.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        //label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        label.textColor = .red

        let sv = UIStackView()
        sv.axis = .horizontal

        // LEAVING DEFAULTS
        //sv.distribution = .fill
        //sv.alignment = .center
        
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // constraint the stack view to the bottomBar view
        bottomBar.addSubview(sv)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            sv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomBar.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            sv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomBar.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            sv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomBar.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
            sv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomBar.topAnchor, constant: 8)
        ])

        sv.addArrangedSubview(messageTextField)
        sv.addArrangedSubview(label)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            messageTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo:sv.heightAnchor),
        ])
    }
```

This is the outcome:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for your answer Luca. It works but the layout debugger says both arranged subviews have ambiguous sizing (width and horizontal position). It looks like a recovering behavior of UIStackView in an ambitious situation. I mean, what if I had 4 views (I want to add some buttons on the left), how to tell one of the view to stretch, and the others to compress ?